# Is it safe in PHP when throwing exception after curl_init

Tags: php

Best to explain by example:

```
public function runRequest()
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    //.... Set Curl Options ....
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    if ($response === false)
        throw new Exception('Boom! A feck, didnt close $ch');

    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Just wondering is this safe? will the $ch be handled properly.

If not, I can change `$ch` to be a class variable, and destroy in the destructor.

Thoughts? thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$ch` will go out of scope and is thereby eligible for garbage collection. When that happens, the resource will be properly deallocated and closed. At least when the script execution ends, all resources will be properly disposed of. As such, it's not really *necessary* to close resources manually; but it's good practice to keep resource usage as low as possible, especially for long running scripts.

PHP 5.5 features `try..catch..finally`, which allows you to always close such resources even in the event of a thrown exception. (Which I just realized doesn't really apply to this situation though.)

Comment: +1, that's really informative, especially the 5.5 stuff, thanks!

Comment: I could I suppose wrap Curl around its own class, and let the out of scope handle the destruct or would that be overkill?

Comment: @Angel Overkill. As I said, resources are already automatically deallocated when they go out of scope, wrapping this already existing functionality in yet another class is pointless.

Comment: Excellent answer. As for overkill, I'd prefer to use an already made OO wrapper for curl. The system as it stands is ridiculously annoying to use. (For Codeigniter f.ex. there is an excellent CURL Spark by Phil Sturgeon)

Comment: Alternatively, check out [Artax](https://github.com/rdlowrey/Artax) - gets rid of the annoying reliance on cURL.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to close the handle before throwing the exception.

```
if (!$response)
{
    curl_close($ch);
    throw new Exception('Boom! No response...');
}
```

When you throw an exception, it'll stop executing any more of your code in that section and bubble right up to where you catch it, else you'll get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception
```

On the flip side, if you *don't* close the handle, it's not really *that* big of an issue. Just don't make a habit of it ;)

However, looking at your code again, your exception doesn't make sense. You *will* have closed it in this case...

Comment: Why does it not make sense?

Comment: Because your exception is being thrown to say you didn't close `$ch`, but the if statement preceding it doesn't check whether or not you closed `$ch` :)

Comment: The exception description is descriptive to get my point across, but it throws on the response failing. Hence why I am wondering would PHP clean up properly if I throw an exception and not close curl

Comment: Ahh, yep it'd clean up fine :) You don't need to worry about it, it's all automatic.